# how can we add a jQuery Library in phtml file Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, jquery, drop-downs

I am using below code in my phtml file.
[image]

Afte using below code:

province drop down is not showing.
[image]

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console? The problem most likely is in the fact that magento comes with jquery library already so your injection outside the requirejs ecosystem may mess something there. Check magento devdocs (https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/javascript-dev-guide/bk-javascript-dev-guide.html) to learn the proper way to add custom js scripts.

Comment: In Magento 2 we are already having the jquery then why you are invoking it from the external link?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery should have been loaded by Magento 2 by default.

You should be able to do this:

```
<script>
    require([
        'jquery'
    ], function($){
        $(document).ready( function() {
            $("#btn_checkall").click(function(){
               //your code
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

As you can see no need to add another jQuery, you are simply calling Magento 2 loaded jQuery.

Hope this helps.